# I have installed ubuntu into my windows 7 64 bit, i am having problems with boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have a problem I have not found any solution to, I am not so familiar with ubuntu commands or ubuntu in general. My problem started when I chose in windows 7 settings/ bootloader settings as ubuntu default, and it boots straight into grub, and in grub if I choose windows, it goes to the loader for half a sec, and goes straight back to grub. So I have disabled my windows 7 completely. And I have not found any way to boot back to windows, so I could go to settings and set it to windows...
My only option seems to be re-installing the whole Windows 7...thus loosing all my saved games etc... I am fine using ubuntu for basic needs, but I am getting desperate here...

Comment: Do you mean your dual boot install worked fine till you changed some settings in Win7?

Comment: Yep, linux works like a charm, no problem there. But the very clever windows boot loader goes straight to grub, and when i choose windows in grub it goes to the windows oh so nice dual boot loader and as the default is set to Ubuntu it just skips right back to Grub. I would need a way to magically boot into my windows so i can change it back to win by default, and never touch that configuration again in my life...

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue how to change Win7 bootloader settings from Ubuntu.
A possible workaround could be:

1. Fix Win7 bootloader (excerpt from [here](http://kb.acronis.com/content/1507)):

   > **Windows Vista or Windows 7 installation CD/DVD**
   >
   > Boot from Windows Vista installation disc, select language and
   >   keyboard or input method, click Next and choose to Repair your
   >   computer. Then you will need to select the operating system that you
   >   want to repair. In the System Recovery Options dialog box click
   >   Command Prompt and type the following:
   >
   > `Bootrec.exe /FixMbr`
   >   `Bootrec.exe /FixBoot`
   >
   > If you want to completely rebuild Windows Vista Boot Configuration
   >   Data, then you should issue the following command:
   >
   > `Bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd`
   >
   > This command scans all disks for installations that are compatible
   >   with Windows Vista. Additionally, this option also allows select the
   >   installations that you want to add to the Boot Configuration Data
   >   store.
   >
   > Further information is available at
   >   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/ More information
   >
   > Please keep in mind that fixmbr is supported only on x86-based
   >   machines.
2. Start Windows and restore previous boot settings;
3. Start Ubuntu from LiveCD or LiveUSB are from type from terminal `sudo update-grub`